# A <Router> may have only one child element inside BrowserRouter

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-redux, react-router-dom

I am trying to pass router context to `sidebar` component I am getting this error A `<Router>` may have only one child element Error in react.

```
return (
  <BrowserRouter>
    {({ router }) => (
      <div style={{ display: 'flex', flex: '1' }}>
        {isAuthenticated &&
        <Sidebar
          router={router}
          rooms={currentUserRooms}
          onLogoutClick={this.handleLogout}
        />
        }
        <MatchAuthenticated exactly pattern="/" component={Home} {...authProps} />
        <RedirectAuthenticated pattern="/login" component={Login} {...authProps} />
        <RedirectAuthenticated pattern="/signup" component={Signup} {...authProps} />
        <MatchAuthenticated pattern="/r/:id" component={Room} {...authProps} />
        <Switch component={NotFound} />
      </div>
    )}
  </BrowserRouter>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The proper way is to use `context`, not to pass `router` as prop.

```js
return (
  <BrowserRouter>
      <div style={{ display: 'flex', flex: '1' }}>
        {isAuthenticated &&
        <Sidebar
          rooms={currentUserRooms}
          onLogoutClick={this.handleLogout}
        />
        }
        <MatchAuthenticated exactly pattern="/" component={Home} {...authProps} />
        <RedirectAuthenticated pattern="/login" component={Login} {...authProps} />
        <RedirectAuthenticated pattern="/signup" component={Signup} {...authProps} />
        <MatchAuthenticated pattern="/r/:id" component={Room} {...authProps} />
        <Switch component={NotFound} />
      </div>
  </BrowserRouter>
);
```

Define `Sidebar` like this:

```js
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

const Sidebar = (props, context) => {...}

Sidebar.contextTypes = {
    router: PropTypes.object,
}
```

From `Sidebar` you then access `context.router`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the withRouter HOC from react-router.

```
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { withRouter } from 'react-router'

const Sidebar = withRouter((props, context) => {...})
```

Reference: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/withRouter.md